# asp.net application userprincipal.findbyidentity works with browser on server, throws exception from my machine

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, directoryservices, active-directory-group, userprincipal

I have an application that is running on an IIS 7 server, in this program I need to find all the groups that the current user is a member of. When I access the website using the browser on the server, it works perfectly, but when I try to access it from my machine it keeps throwing a COM exception, Here is the code I'm using to get the user groups.

```
private List<string> GetUserGroups(string userName)
{
    //The list of strings for output.
    List<string> output= new List<string>();
    try
    {
        //creating a PrincipalContext object in a using block for easy disposal
        using(PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"domain"))
        //using(WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
        {

            //Creating a UserPrincipal from the PrincipalContext by finding the user that 
            //was passed to the function

            //This is the line that keeps throwing the exception.
            using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain,IdentityType.SamAccountName,userName))
            {
                //Checking to make sure the user was found.
                if (user != null)
                {
                    //Getting the users groups in a collection variable called groups
                    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = UserPrincipal.Current.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                    //IdentityReferenceCollection groups = user.Groups;
                    //This foreach loop goes through each result in the groups collection
                    foreach (Principal p in groups)
                    {
                        //check the result is a GroupPrincipal object and is not null
                        if (p is GroupPrincipal && p.ToString() != null)
                        {
                            output.Add(p.ToString());//Add the string value to the output list.
                            debugString += "<br/>"+p.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        processLog.Text += ex.ToString()+ ex.GetType();
    }
    //return the list of groups the user is a member of.
    return output;
}
```

Why does it throw the exception when I access it from a location other than the server? How can I fix it?

Update:
Here is the stacktrace exception and all

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072020): An
>   operations error occurred. at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() at
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() at
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry
>   entry, String propertyName) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String
>   propertyName) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String
>   identityValue, DateTime refDate) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String
>   identityValue) at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext
>   context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue) at
>   ResetUnlockAccount.ResetUnlockAccount.GetUserGroups(String userName)
>   in
>   C:\ResetUnlockAccount\ResetUnlockAccount\ResetUnlockAccount.aspx.cs:line
>   894

Comment: Is there an `InnerException` object that the COM Exception is wrapping?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, I tried to print it out and it said I was trying to access a null value, so no, I don't think so, I'll try again to be sure.

Comment: In your catch, you can add a check for `(ex.InnerException != null)`; if that's the case, `processLog.Text += ex.InnerException.ToString());`

Comment: I just did that, and there is no inner exception, the out exception is System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: COM should be giving you an error code.. either as decimal or hex. That'll be invaluable for googling.

Comment: Also - what line is it excepting on?

Comment: I pointed out the line in the original code, its on the UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity, and where would I find this code?

Comment: Sorry; missed that when I went scanning to look for it.

Comment: See if [this post has any relevant answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7285503/656243)

Comment: Also, you may want to post the output of ex.ToString(), exception, stacktrace, and all...

Comment: One last consideration: is there any evidence in the event log?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I'm checking out that link, looks like the error code is the same, so I'll see if I can get it figured out, thanks so much for your help

Comment: Good luck. I still feel like there should be an hex COM error being spit out with that exception message.

Comment: Oh! There is -- 0x80072020

Comment: Then also, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7969425/656243

Comment: And lastly -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/15001395/656243

Comment: For now, I'll shut up and let you research. Don't forget to come back and write up an answer. I'm sure you'll have a revelation in the next hour or so.

Comment: The answer was found here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969425/groupprincipal-method-findbyidentity-throw-strange-exception
Thanks to Lynn Crumbling for the links,

just had to add
   
    using System.Web.Hosting;
    
and 

    using(HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())

over the first using in the original code.

Comment: Can't answer my own question, not enough rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the OP's comment,

> The answer was found here: [GroupPrincipal method FindByIdentity throw strange exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7969425/656243)
>
> Just had to add `using System.Web.Hosting;` and
>   `using(HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())` over the first using in the
>   original code.